# iOS - how to read and write a plist of this format

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I have an xml of the following format -

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>...</dict>
    <dict>...</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I am trying to write it into a plist using -

```
NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:returnData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format error:&errorDesc];
[self writeToPlistFile:@"myList.plist" : temp];
```

where the method is

```
-(BOOL)writeToPlistFile:(NSString*)filename:(NSDictionary*)data{
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
BOOL didWriteSuccessfull = [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
return didWriteSuccessfull;
}
```

I then want to read it and place it into a dictionary. How would I do that?

Comment: Your top level object is an Array, not a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this if the plist starts with an `<array>` tag

`NSMutableArray* documentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath];`

where sourcePath is the path to your plist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following replacing filePath with the same path you used to save it.

```
NSDictionary *yourDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)saveData:(NSString*)data
{
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.txt",documentDirectory,1];
        NSString *content=data;
        NSFileHandle *fileHandler= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileName];
        [fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];
        [fileHandler writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [fileHandler closeFile];
        NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
}
```